# How to add an UpdatePanel controls to a page programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I use asp.net 4 and c#.
I would like to use AJAX Control UpdatePanel to my page.

I read in the documentation that

```
UpdatePanel controls can be added declaratively or programmatically.
```

But I could not find out any information how to programmatically add a UpdatePanel controls on a page.

My question: **How to add an UpdatePanel controls to a page programmatically?** (Please note I need add the actual Update Control on a Web Form and not controls inside the UpdatePanel )
Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {

        UpdatePanel updatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
        //updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(linkButton); if want to add control in UpdatePanel
        form1.Controls.Add(updatePanel);
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

more :

[Dynamically Adding an UpdatePanel to Your Page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2007/03/15/dynamically-adding-an-updatepanel-to-your-page.aspx)

http://asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/mref/C_System_Web_UI_UpdatePanel_ctor.aspx

Comment: @Adnan Bhatti  - but he ask to add updatepanel and i m assuming that scripmanager is added on page

Comment: If your scriptmanager is on the masterpage, wont you need to add a scriptmanagerproxy to your content page?

Comment: I did not know about scriptmanagerproxy before, please post an example if you can thanks!

Comment: I know that this is kinda old but: I once read that the biggest problem with hard-core pro developers is that they tend to make simple tasks as complex, interesting and less boring for them as possible. Hence your answer. I'm on my second major project with my company and never had to do anything on initialization, onLoad is always good enough. How is your solution (if any) better than the one provided by MS Stp, apart from being different...

Answer (score 2):

First add ScriptManager then add UpdatePanel

For example.

```
  ScriptManager myScriptManager = new ScriptManager(); 
  UpdatePanel updatePanel1 = new updatePanel();
  this.Controls.Add(myScriptManager);
  this.Controls.Add(updatePanel1);
```

Then set up event handlers.

## Just to Add

Your next question might be that why after postback your UpdatePanel is gone. The answer is the controls you add programamtically you have to add them back on every postback.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try this (untested):

```
UpdatePanel updPanel = new UpdatePanel();
divFields.Controls.Add(FreeText); // where divFields is the id of a div
```

You can also give the control an ID or other attributes before you add it like:

```
updPanel.ID = "updPnlTest";
```

Hope this helps =]